# Which windows server version does support unix socket

Tags: c#, windows, grpc, windows-server

I'd like to use [Inter-process communication with gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interprocess?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (which is based on unix socket).

From [AF_UNIX comes to Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/) :

> Beginning in Insider Build 17063, you’ll be able to use the unix socket (AF_UNIX) address family on Windows to communicate between Win32 processes

This seems to address only windows 10/11

I was unable to find documentation which windows server versions will support unix socket.
Does windows server 2016/2019 support unix socket / Is there any documentation about this?

Edit:
Based on the answer from Seva Alekseyev, i found the build version numbers from [microsoft for windows servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by build numbers. The first version with build number over 17000 is Windows Server 2019. Windows Server 2016 is 14000.

Comment: I wasn't aware that windows 10/11 and server share build numbers.